# Populating an array from ResultSet SQL results

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I retrieved individual `String` values from a database and converted it into a String array by using the String method `split()`.

```
ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM numberLotto");
while(set.next())
{
    num1 = set.getString(1);                   
    num2 = set.getString(2);
    num3 = set.getString(3);
    num4 = set.getString(4);
    num5 = set.getString(5);
    num6 = set.getString(6);
    num7 = set.getString(7);
    totalLotto += num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3 + " " +  num4 + " " +
        num5 + " " +  num6 + " " +  num7 + " " + "/";
}
String[]listOfNumbers = totalLotto.split("/");
```

The resulting output is as follow

```
3 18 27 38 41 45 47     
4 7 11 15 22 33 42
2 9 15 23 24 39 44 
4 11 16 17 35 39 48
```

etc

How could I add the above numbers into an array of an array so that I can loop through each individual number?(and subsequently check if they are contained in a list of winning numbers?)

Kind regards

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, is there a good reason why your database isn't just storing the numbers as a numeric data type to begin with?

Comment: You can get the number of rows returned by the resultset and then declare your multidimensional array before running through the set. Then just fill in the values directly into the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using strings at all?  This seems to be numbers so integers would be a better match:

```
List<int[]> listOfNumbers = new ArrayList<int[]>();
while(set.next()) {
     int[] numbers = new int[7];
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         numbers[i] = set.getInt(i + 1);
     }
     listOfNumbers.add(numbers);
}
```

You obviously could also use `Integer[]` if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the values from the resultSet to an array of Strings and add it to a list.

Example:

```
ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM numberLotto");
List<String[]> lottoList = new LinkedList<String[]>();
while(set.next())
{
  String[] currentRow = new String[] {set.getString(1),
                                      set.getString(2), 
                                      set.getString(3), 
                                      set.getString(4), 
                                      set.getString(5), 
                                      set.getString(6),  
                                      set.getString(7)};
  lottoList.add(currentRow);
}
// do whatever you like with lottoList
```

You can then loop through the lottoList and check how many winning numbers there are.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ArrayList` of `String` arrays:

```
ArrayList<String[]> numbers = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Then further split `listOfNumbers[0]` by space and add the result to the collection:

```
String[] listOfNumbers = totalLotto.split("/");
numbers.add(listOfNumbers[0].split(" "));
```

So assuming `listOfNumbers[0]` is

```
3 18 27 38 41 45 47
```

Splitting by space will give you a `String[]` with a number in each position.

Answer (score 2):

```
ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numberLotto");
String[][] array = new String[rs.getInt(1)][6];

ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM numberLotto");
int i = 0;
    while(set.next())
    {

                array[i][0] = set.getString(1);                   
                array[i][1]= set.getString(2);
                array[i][2]= set.getString(3);
                array[i][3]= set.getString(4);
                array[i][4]= set.getString(5);
                array[i][5]= set.getString(6);
                array[i][6]= set.getString(7);
          i ++;     
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        while (set.next()) {
            int[] array = new int[7];
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
                array[i - 1] = set.getInt(i);
            }

            list.add(array);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, you can change it to your code style

```
String[] a = {"10 20 30 40 50","100 200 300 400 500","1000 2000 3000 4000"};
          String[][] b = new String[a.length][];
          for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
              b[i] = a[i].split(" ");
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM numberLotto");
List<String[]> tmp = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while(set.next())
{
    String[] row = new String[7];
    row [0] = set.getString(1);                   
    row [1] = set.getString(2);
    row [2] = set.getString(3);
    row [3] = set.getString(4);
    row [4] = set.getString(5);
    row [5] = set.getString(6);
    row [6] = set.getString(7);
    tmp.add(row);
}
String[][] listOfNumbers = tmp.toArray(new String[tmp.size()][7]);
```